# Error 403 with stream of unstored tweets

Tags: python

Estoy sacando tweets que se escriben en tiempo real pero me sale que cuando busca, el problema esque me da error 403 y no me da los tweets en tiempo real.
Estoy usando la libreria tweepy. El código que uso es solo para mostrar en consola los últimos tweets y no estoy almacenando. Puse como ejemplo que me busque tweets por la palabra "Cuenca" y al momento de ejecutar me da error 403.

Nota: Las credenciales no son reales

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 

class TweetsListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_connect(self):
        print("Estoy conectado!")
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print("Error", status_code)

consumer_k="000DEGFhopJshfV4O"
consumer_ks="00w8jSxN3QUENV9Ge8Vhx"
access_t="0045500UHavTRcBiIon"
access_ts="00RHwJAoMtdyyI2ABRtN2N"


auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_k,consumer_ks)

auth.set_access_token(access_t,access_ts)
todos los métodos de la api
api=tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, wait_on_rate_limit=True) 


stream = TweetsListener()
streamingApi = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream)
streamingApi.filter(track=["Cuenca"])
```

El problema esta aqui

````
stream = TweetsListener()
streamingApi = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream)
streamingApi.filter(track=["Cuenca"])```
````

Comment: Me parece que el error está con tus credenciales. Acabo de probar tu código con mis propias credenciales y me funciona [EJEMPLO](https://i.imgur.com/IXT8L59.png), o quizás el fallo podría ser que tú api de twitter es muy nueva y no tiene el nivel de acceso suficiente, puede obtener uno mayor [aqui](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve%22,%22code%22:453) solo tienes que rellenar la info que te pide twitter

Comment: Por cierto, si esas son tus credenciales reales no tienes que compartirlas, especialmente las de 'access' porque básicamente son la contraseña de tu cuenta de twitter.

Comment: En base al ultimo comentario de CalumRakk, te diría que regeneres tus credenciales si es que estas son las reales. Editar la pregunta no es una opción (ya que hay historial de ediciones).

Comment: Te han dejado comentarios respecto a tu codigo, podrias tomarte el trabajo de contestar? sobre todo, porque algunas personas se preocuparon por la seguridad de tus cuetnas...

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, si lo que puse son claves no reales. Corrí la programación  examinando la API en Twitter pero no, me sigue dando error 403.

Comment: Adjunto lo que me sale:

KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)

   1 stream = TweetsListener()2 streamingApi = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream)
 3 streamingApi.filter(track=["Cuenca"])


    279                         self.retry_time = max(self.retry_420_start,
    280                                               self.retry_time)
--> 281                     sleep(self.retry_time)
    282                     self.retry_time = min(self.retry_time * 2,
    283                                           self.retry_time_cap)